# Java DOM : getElementsByTagNameNS for an element in NO namespace

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-namespaces

I've noticed that when used with a namespace-aware `DocumentBuilderFactory`:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new File("sample.xml"));
```

Using either a `null` or a zero-length string `""` in the call to `getElementsByTagNameNS` will produce the elements with the provided *localName* that are in NO namespace at all (excluding elements with that *localName* that might be in a namespace) :

```
NodeList foo1 = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(null, "localname");
NodeList foo2 = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(""  , "localname");
```

However, the (non-linkable) [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) for **Element::getElementsByTagNameNS** is rather ambiguous and does not explicitly mention that a null pointer or the zero-length string can be used for the no-namespace elements. Can I rely on this behavior ?

Comment: I think this is a gray area and I would not rely on it across all DOM implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM generally uses null for the "unnamed namespace". This is explicit in some methods. But if it's not in the spec, you can't rely on it. (Most people writing DOM applications only ever test them against one DOM implementation, and they can be in for nasty surprises when they find it only works with that implementation.)

Another reason not to use DOM - there are much better alternatives available!